# Как лучше всего сделать отступы в моём случае?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, отступы

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У меня несколько вариантов:

1. создать отдельный див и поместить туда весь контент (хедер, контент, футер и тд) для этого дива задать максимальную ширину к примеру 1170пх и margin: 0 auto; То есть так:

```css
.width {
  max-width: 1170px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="width">
    <header></header>
    <content></content>
    <footer></footer>
  </div>
</body>
```

2. Либо для width прописать padding
3. Для body прописать padding или margin (тут я тоже хз что лучше)

Подскажите как лучше всего это сделать? Мб 1,2 или 3 варианты?

Comment: с лева и с права это не просто отступы посмотри какое нить видео про верстку поймеш

Comment: 1 вариант ;) и у этого контейнера с дoисторических времен есть имя .container

Comment: и он внутри обычно а не с наружи